# How to send Android Crash report using ACRA

Tags: android, exception, crash, crash-reports, acra

Am trying to send crash report from my applicatio to my domain or Mail but failed still.

To get the crash report in mail, I did

@ReportsCrashes(

```
      formKey = "",
      mailTo = "abc@gmail.com"
  )
```

And the response is,
Sending file 1372758321000-approved.stacktrace

## checkAndSendReports - finish

To get the crash report in my domain, I did

@ReportsCrashes(

```
      formKey = "",
      formUri = "http://www.abc.com/test1"
)
```

And the response is,
Sending file 1372856882000-approved.stacktrace
Failed to send crash report for 1372856882000-approved.stacktrace
org.acra.sender.ReportSenderException: Error while sending FORM report via Http POST

Any help will be handy for me and appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ACRA works for me sending reports by e-mail when I do exactly as they say in their docs:

```
@ReportsCrashes(mailTo = "reports@yourdomain.com", // my email here
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
```

https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations#sending-reports-by-email

You are probably forgetting the toast part. Or can it be you don't have an e-mail program (such as when you're running on the simulator).

I think sending reports by Google docs are not supported anymore.

Comment: I am trying to run acra in my application which is working fine to me. But the problem is I didn't get any email from there.please help me

Answer (score 6):

Your application class should look like this.

```
import android.app.Application;

    import org.acra.ACRA;
    import org.acra.ReportField;
    import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
    import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;


    @ReportsCrashes(mailTo = "user@domain.com", customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE, ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION, ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
            ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA, ReportField.STACK_TRACE, ReportField.LOGCAT},
            mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST, resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            ACRA.init(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

No，not like Alex say,the mode property has no releation to the reporting type,you can see it in the source code in github
using the mailTo type，you should make sure that:

1. your app has the permission to connect network;
2. have an e-mail program in your device like Alex say;
3. have you invoked the ACRA.init(this) method in your application's oncreate()?

if all of these have done,then run your app,it will note you to configure the email,such as username and password and so on.

Comment: I don't think an app has to have INTERNET permission to mail reports by ACRA

Comment: yes,you are right,has the Internet permission is not must.I tried it again,I found that,the formKey must be not null,if it is null,when the app crashed,the android system will show a dialog for you to choose a program to process,even though you select the email program,it still won't be send email.

Comment: besides,the mode property is not the must,if you configured it,when you app crashed,the system will not popup the crash window