# How to email logcat debugging info?

Tags: android, logcat

In order to debug a user problem I can't reproduce, I am trying to put a button into my app that gathers up logcat output and emails it.  I am having trouble.

First, I tried to use [acra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463237/how-to-send-android-crash-report-using-acra#17463340).  I dropped down one rathole for awhile.  I got

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: Error while generating the main dex list.
at ...
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat
```

and read about trying to resolve clashing classes from different libraries (e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038630/android-compilation-error-with-v7-support-lib-27-1-0-program-type-already-pres), but there were more I can't find).

I decided to try a simpler way, outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25765772/34935): a single function to grab the logs with logcat and email.  One wrinkle is that [newer versions of android don't let you grab that file directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/34935), you have to use a FileProvider.

I ended up with this:

```
/**
 * Save logcat in a file and return an Intent that emails it.
 *
 * @return  intent to email log file
 */
private static Intent sendLogcatMail() {
    // save logcat in file
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "logcat.txt");
    try {
        // last 2000 lines of the log, in 'time' format
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "logcat -v time -t 2000 -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOGGER_TAG, "Error in logcat:" + Tools.getStackTrace(e));
    }

    Log.i(LOGGER_TAG, "logcat size: " + outputFile.length());
    //send file using email
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    // Set type to "email"
    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
    String to[] = {SEND_LOGS_EMAIL};
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    // FileProvider
    // See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/34935
    // See https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en
    Uri logUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Tools.getContext(),
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            outputFile);
    // the attachment
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, logUri);
    // the mail subject
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App logs");
    return Intent.createChooser(emailIntent , "Send email...");
}
```

Now when I run in the simulator, that debug line shows the logcat file is always of size zero, even though I see the logcat in Android Studio.  I tried emphasizing that my app was debuggable with this in my build.gradle:

```
   release {
        // ...
        // make sure logcat gets debug output
        debuggable true
    }
```

That did nothing.

How can I gather up debug logs to email them, or otherwise get them from a remote app to where I can see them?   I am utterly confused.

Comment: I suggest to use firebase crash reporting it's really make the life easier

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. First, it's already been deprecated for Crashalytics: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/03/firebase-crashlytics-graduates-from-beta.html.  Second, I don't have a crash. The app just isn't functioning correctly (not uploading things when it's on wifi).

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime#exec` does not wait for the process to be completed (or even to be started, perhaps). So you need to invoke `waitFor()` on the result in order to await `logcat` termination:

```
int exitStatus = Runtime.getRuntime()
        .exec("logcat -v time -t 2000 -f " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .waitFor();
if (exitStatus != 0) {
    // Something went wrong running logcat, handle error. Output file might not exist.
}
```